# What's wrong with my register broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I have a MyBroadcastReceiver class implemented, and I tried to register one broadcast receiver in runtime with:

```
String MY_ACTION = "DUMMY";
MyBroadcastReceiver receiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(MY_ACTION);
Log.i(TAG, "intentFilter: " + intentFilter.getAction(0));
Intent intent = context.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
Log.i(TAG, "intent returned after registering:" + intent);
Intent queryIntent = new Intent(MY_ACTION);
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = pm.queryBroadcastReceivers(queryIntent, 0);
Log.i(TAG, "list of receivers:" + resolveInfos.toString());
```

I ran a broadcasting from the adb shell:

```
am broadcast \
-n com.foo.foo.foo/.MyBroadcastReceiver \
-a DUMMY
```

I also have some Log.i in my onReceive() (implemented inside MyBroadcast Receiver).

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   Log.i(TAG, "in Broadcasting Receiver anyway");
   if (intent != null) {
     ...
   }
 }
```

}

The result is:

- the log of intentFilter.getAction(0) gives the right action
- the log of intent after registering gives null
- I got empty receivers' list from log.
- And the onReceive has never been entered(from the log I could see
  that)

I guess there are some errors with my register part?
Any hints/advice will be hight appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
Intent intent = context.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
```

will return `null` because it only returns "sticky" broadcasts. This is correct, as you aren't sending a "sticky" broadcast.

This code:

```
List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = pm.queryBroadcastReceivers(queryIntent, 0);
```

should return an empty list because this code only returns `BroadcastReceiver`s that have been registered in the manifest with `<receiver>` tags, and does NOT return anything for dynamically registered `BroadcastReceiver`s, which your `MyBroadcastReceiver` is.

I do not know why `onReceive()` was not called. Please post your `MyBroadcastReceiver` code. I don't see anything obvious. You could try this adb command instead:

```
am broadcast -a DUMMY
```

You could also try adding

```
sendBroadcast(queryIntent);
```

after this code:

```
Intent queryIntent = new Intent(MY_ACTION);
```

and see if this calls your `onReceive()`.

Comment: thanks. have updated question with my code of MyBroadcastReceiver.

Comment: Added another idea at the end of my answer. Also, what is `context` in your code `context.registerReceiver()`? Are you calling this from an `Activity` or a `Service` or what?

Comment: the context is obtained by using context.getApplicationContext() and loop through it.

Comment: The problem seems to be that am broadcast -n XXX won't work for the dynamic registered broadcast receiver. Thanks for your help!